# Approximation of $2^n$ for large $n$

Tags: approximation

Is there some sort of approximation for $2^n$? I'm specifically interested in how the ratio $\frac{2n}{2^n}$ scales for large $n$ (apart from decreasing to zero in the limit)

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.06/h/nick1.html
Conclusion: Logarithms.

Comment: You have $\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$ which gets very small as n goes large. In fact as n approaches infinity, the expression approaches zero.

Comment: I suggest you clarify your question.

Comment: The usual approximation for $2^n$ is $2^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r_n = \frac{2n}{2^n}$. Then
$$
\frac{r_{n+1}}{r_n}=\frac12\left(1+\frac1n\right) \to \frac12
$$
In words, for large $n$, we have that $r_{n+1}$ is approximately half of $r_n$ but slightly greater.